# EXTJS 4 change row collor without CSS

Tags: extjs

Could you prompt me how to change grid row background color without using CSS?
I found the following procedure, but can't find what should I return. I hope that's why it's not working:

```
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams, ds) {
              rowParams.tstyle = 'width:' + this.getTotalWidth() + ';';
              if (set_background) {
                 rowParams.tstyle += "background-color:" + bgColor + ';';
              }
              if (set_foreground) {
                 rowParams.tstyle += "color:" + fgColor + ';';
              }
        }
  }
```

Be so kind as to advise.

Comment: there is some problem with your rowParams i think try to use renderer  event

Comment: getRowClass using for return CSS class, you can't use it to add style without class, you need to find another solution

Comment: yes, I know getRowClass is for CSS but I found this suggestion on net

Comment: what do you think saying "use renderer event" raghavendra?